# PHP whats wrong with my syntax

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, nested-if

I have this syntax here:

```
$savings = $savings == '' ? null : $savings;
```

`$savings` comes from `$_POST['savings']` which comes from an input number field and I left it empty, so it should be equal to '' but when I `print_r($savings`) I get nothing, I was expecting `null`.

Comment: Make sure you `trim()` your values and use `empty()` to see if that value really is an empty value.

Comment: that did not work at all, when I print_r ($savings) nothing returns, I am expecting 'null' to appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$savings = empty($savings) ? null : $savings;
```

Comment: What will that second one achieve?

Comment: the ternary operator is ugly, but your second one is even worse.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You do not need to write again `$savings` for the non-empty case.

Comment: Doesn't the second return `true` ? (as in !empty($savings) ? !empty($savings) : null)

Comment: @DamienPirsy Second one is equivalent to: `!empty($savings) ? $savings : null`

Comment: @VWGolf2 Ugly or not - it's available.

Comment: +1 didn't know yet about the ternary operator with the true expression empty.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Oh my, I've made a fool of myself. Sorry !

Comment: actually it does, my bad :)